# Dynamic Time Warping for waveform similarity in real time

Tags: similarity, waveform

Could anyone give some recommended resources/links on DTW and how DTW can be used for measuring waveform similarity?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a website with code/videos
http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/UCRsuite.html

If you need a more basic tutorial, there is one here
http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/Keogh_Time_Series_CDrom.zip
pass is      peggy

a preview http://www.cs.ucr.edu/~eamonn/sampleslides2.jpg

eamonn